# Integrating paypal recurring

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I am new to PayPal integrating and need to integrate PayPal recurring for subscriptions. I googled for that, but I am confused with below questions.

1. Which API should I use with PayPal recurring, WPS or Paypal express checkout? Which one will be good?
2. Is there any good example or help to integrate this?

Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Good overview of recurring payments: [Handling recurring payments](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECRecurringPayments)

I'm using the [Lionite PHP Paypal class](http://www.binpress.com/app/php-paypal-api-class/20). It's not free, but even if you're not going to use it, read through that page because it contains some useful info that is omitted from the Paypal docs.

If I understand correctly, Express Checkout requires your customer to set up a Paypal account, so Website Payments Standard would be a better option.

Unfortunately the Paypal SDK only has code examples for direct payment. If you want to use Website Payments Pro with Direct Payment, be aware of PCI compliance (which can be expensive and time-consuming) and also be aware that services like [BrainTree](http://www.braintreepayments.com) exist which have transparent redirect, thus helping you to avoid PCI compliance (I haven't used this service however).

Express checkout code example: https://github.com/hrendoh/PayPal-Recurring-Payment-example

Set up your sandbox account at http://developer.paypal.com

**Update**: IPN for recurring payments is a nightmare. Not only are the recurring payment IPN responses completely undocumented, but none of the support staff I talked to had a clue about them either (in some cases they gave me incorrect answers to questions). Here is a list that others have put together, but all of these resources are incomplete:

https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/ppmacole/recurring-payments-ipns?page=1

http://docs.ipn-easy.com/html/T_Rolosoft_IpnEasy_Net_PayPal_TxnType.htm

Unfortunately because of the limits placed on recurring payments with express checkout, direct payment was the only option for me. I **strongly** suggest that if you need to do direct payment with recurring payments that you find a different payment provider.

Comment: Having exactly the same experience with IPN. The API is woeful and developer support haven't a clue.